# Chrome Extension - Trigger not Work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i try create simple Chrome Extension, after click button in pop-up, i need send function setInput() to page, function change value and i need use trigger('keyup'), if i try use this function in Chrome Console - trigger work. But if i send this function after click in pop-up -  trigger not work(

Chrome Extension - Trigger not Work

[image]

Console - Trigger Work

[image]

popup.html

```
<head>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="btn">Click</div>
</body>
```

popup.js

```
function sendMessage() {
    chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs){
    var activeTab = tabs[0];
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(activeTab.id, {"message": "start"});
   });
}

function onWindowLoad() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "PageReader.js" });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    btn.addEventListener('click', function() {

        sendMessage();

    });
});

window.onload = onWindowLoad;
```

PageReader.js

```
- in file top i include Jquery

    function setInput() {
        var input = $('.text input');
        input.val('1111').trigger('keyup');
    }

    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
        function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
            if( request.message === "start" ) {
                setInput();
            }
        }
    );
```

Comment: one question: why are you executing script for your tabs: chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "PageReader.js" });`. Why don't you use contentscript.js

Comment: I'm noob, this is the first experience of creating an extension, you mean add   "content_scripts" in file Manifest?

Comment: Yes, Read this
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Answer (score 1):

thanks all for help, i find answer, i delete jQuery, and create event "keyup"

Old:

```
var input = $('.text input');
input.val('1111').trigger('keyup');
```

New:

```
var evt = document.createEvent('KeyboardEvent');
evt.initEvent('keyup', true, true);
var input = document.querySelector('.text input');
input.value = '1111';
input.dispatchEvent(evt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `debugger` after `btn.addEventListener('click', function() {` too see what is going on. if this event handler is attached.

**Second thing** - you may want to wrap you initialisation code into `setTimeout` call with let's say 100ms of delay, to check if this page you are dealing with is not only working with some framework that generates this HTML and this is done after `DOMContentLoaded`. This means basically wrap everything inside

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
```

with `setTimeout(function() {/*everything inside goes here*/}, 100)`